# asset become invisible in Internet Explorer 10 after bounceInDown animation ends

Tags: jquery, css, animate.css

Please take a look here:

https://codepen.io/copperjohn/pen/vgKeQj

There's a logo set at display:none and then made visible with jquery and animated by animate.css

```
$('.banner').show('slow');
$('.banner').addClass('animated bounceInDown modifica_animation');
```

after BounceInDown animation ends the image is no more visible in Internet Explorer 10+ (it is still visible in Chrome, Firefox, Safari).

can help?
thanks
Francesco

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should fire the addClass first, then show the div.

```
$('.banner').addClass('animated bounceInDown modifica_animation');
$('.banner').show('slow');
```

Comment: Hmmm, it seems to work on my comp. Here is the screen video capture of  your codepen snippet https://www.screencast.com/t/SsiojsbsTb. And here it is when I fliped those two functions like I said above https://www.screencast.com/t/dee9PlkiXBSL.